# functional keys in vim in xterm

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, xterm

Functional keys (F1-F12) for **vim in console** don't work.
But the worst thing is when I hit such key, vim stays in some "mode" not allowing me to type anything for 2s... Very annoying

Another thing is after pressing Esc key vim pause for about 0.5s before go to normal mode.. But this is only happening in **screen**, even I set

```
export TERM=xterm
```

Anybody has some clean and short solution?

Comment: I couldn't post here smile ":)" after word "annoying". Reason: does not meet our quality standards... :)

Comment: Vim has nothing to do with console not working, my Vim instance works great with functional keys. What you are looking for is your console setting and the mode you use. By default these keys are not mapped, how can you tell they are not working? What is your mapping? For me Vim works in both urxvt and xterm pretty well.

Comment: I don't know what is my mapping. I've probably never change it. How I can check it?

Comment: Is your TERM correct *outside* of `screen`? This is the important one.

Comment: Regarding the escape delay: you probably want something like `maptimeout 0` in your `.screenrc`.

Comment: Thanks Itay Perl. That works great!

Comment: I had alias v="vim -T builtin_ansi". sorry for not necessary question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some disagreement between the byte sequences vim thinks the terminal is going to send, and the sequences it actually does.

Also the half-second delay is a consequence of having some mappings that start with Escape.

Comment: It was my wrong defined terminal type. But that half-second delay it was really screen fault. Adding `maptimeout 0` is a solution. I'm wonder why screen have such delay...